# How could I create a diagram for bond pricing?

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I am writing a paper and I need to create a basic diagram for zero coupon bond pricing, something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (10,0);

    \draw[|-|] 
        (A)
        node at (A) [above=5pt,color =green] {$P_{t,M}$} 
        node at (A) [below=5pt,color =green] {$t$}
        --
        (B)
        node at (B) [above=5pt,color =green] {$N$}
        node at (B) [below=5pt,color =green] {$t + M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```